# Python parsing date with strptime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-parsing

I have url that returns date in this format

```
url_date = "2015-01-12T08:43:02Z"
```

I don't know why there are strings, it would have been simpler to get it as `"2015-01-1208:43:02"` which would have been simpler to parse using

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(url_date , '%Y-%m-%d')
```

but it does not work. I have tried with

```
%Y-%m-%d
%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S
%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%Z
```

But I keep getting errors like "time data 2015-01-12T08:43:02Z does not match ..."

Comment: related: [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format you are looking for is - `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'` .

Example -

```
>>> url_date = "2015-01-12T08:43:02Z"
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(url_date , '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 12, 8, 43, 2)
```

---

For the new requirement in comments -

> if I wanted to get a time back with the strings as in 2015-01-12:08:43:02 which methods should after datetime().datetime()

You would need to use `.strftime()` on the `datetime.datetime` object with the format - `'%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S'`. Example -

```
>>> url_date = "2015-01-12T08:43:02Z"
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(url_date , '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S')
'2015-01-12:08:43:02'
```

If you wanted the time component , you can use `.time()` for that. Example -

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(url_date , '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
>>> dt.time()
datetime.time(8, 43, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, just one quick question .. if I wanted to get a time back with the strings as in 2015-01-12:08:43:02 which methods should after datetime().datetime()

Comment: You want the result as a string? And in that format? If so, check the `.strftime()` example given above.

Comment: I just want it as as string, like your first example `2015-01-12:08:43:02` which I just tried btw, and I get `error, required argument 'format' (pos 1) not found`

Answer (score 5):

You were getting close with the "Z" in your final attempt - you need to specify the T, Z, and colon literal values in your format string.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> url_date = "2015-01-12T08:43:02Z"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(url_date , '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 12, 8, 43, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, just one quick question .. if I wanted to get a time back with the strings as in `2015-01-12:08:43:02` which methods should after `datetime().datetime()` ?

Comment: in a nutshell, I would like to submit the time to database, and the `DATETIME` field can not accept more than specific number of digits, namely `2015-10-4:06:13:22` so, I would just like to know how it get that back

Comment: So you want to convert it _from_ a datetime, _to_ a string? Use `datetime_obj.strftime("%Y-%m%d:%H:%M:%S")`.