# Importing a Text File with dates, times and data points and plotting into Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm starting out as a Research Assistant at a lab at UMD and I am having trouble with the coding aspect of the work. I am running python 2.7.12 w/ Anaconda 4.2.0. I was given a text file with the task of reading it into python and graphing it using matplotlib. The text file is in this format

> 20170109 001203 379.00 22824.13 1.00

where the last two columns can be ignored, the first is the date, the second is the time in `HH:MM:SS`. and the third column is `ppm (parts per million)`.

I have been able to read the data into python but have not figured out how to differentiate the first two columns as dates and times. I am thinking of doing something using datetime but am not sure what inputs I should use. From there I would like to plot the data with time (both `yyyy MMM dddd` and `HH MM SS`) on the x-axis, and ppm on the y-axis, using matplotlib through numpy.

Comment: Look at [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html)!

Comment: You’re looking for the `strptime` method—there’s an example of how to use it in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397107/python-parsing-date-with-strptime) and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the interesting part of the input, you can slice the input string

```
input = '20170109 001203 379.00 22824.13 1.00'

input_date = input[:15]
print(input_date)

input_ppm = input[16:23]
print(input_ppm)
```

Later, use `strptime` function to parse a string into date with time.

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')
print(dt)
```

Now you can use `dt` as x-axis points. To see how to use dates in Matplotlib, you can check this [Matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo2.html).

Good luck!

**EDIT**
To read the file with multiple lines, you can use `readlines()` which will create a list. You can loop over that list to extract each line and parse it to date & time.

Whole code now will look like this:

```
import datetime

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# content is now a list of text line strings

# remove whitespaces, e.g. newline character
content = [x.strip() for x in content] 

for input in content:
    input_date = input[:15]
    print(input_date)

    input_ppm = input[16:23]
    print(input_ppm)

    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')
    print(dt)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this is a great start. The problem I'm running into now is that this works great for doing one line at a time but the text file contains multiple lines. Is there a way to do this in bulk so the entire file is read into this format? thanks in advance!

Comment: @SebastianSuarez I edited the answer to add the information you asked for. Basically you read a file to a list of strings. Then you wrap previously used code with for loop. If it was helpful, you can sign it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the date strings are going to have the same format...

```
from datetime import datetime

input = "20170109 001203 379.00 22824.13 1.00"

list = input.split(" ") #Split the input into parts where blank space is the delimiter
date_and_time = str([' '.join(list[:2])]) #Merge the first item with the second and convert to string
#Insert all the white spaces we need to then convert to date time object
date_and_time = date_and_time[2:6]+' '+date_and_time[6:8]+' '+date_and_time[8:10]+' '+date_and_time[11:13]+' '+date_and_time[13:15]+' '+date_and_time[15:-2]

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_and_time, '%Y %m %d %H %M %S')
print (datetime_object)
```

The reason this is tricky is because you need to somehow differentiate between the different units of time when you do your string -> date conversion. Code is very crude but it should provide some insight to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by splitting up the text file:

```
text = '20170109 001203 379.00 22824.13 1.00'
texts = text.split(" ")
print(texts)
```

Then you could extract it bit by bit with date:

```
date = datetime.strptime(texts[0], '%Y%m%d')
print("The day is {}".format(date.day))
time = datetime.strptime(texts[1], '%H%M%S')
print("The minute is {}".format(time.minute))
ppm = texts[2]
print("ppm is {}".format(ppm))
```

If you get stuck in the plotting you should open up a new question. I recommend going here http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html and clicking on a plot you like. It will provide all the code you need.